# trying to catch all conditions for URL redirect in htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a htaccess file that will redirect all possible URLs to the correct format.

I want all URLs to be in the format:

```
https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/mypage
```

All my website pages are filename.php

My current htaccess code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

This works well for almost all conditions, but if I click on a link like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/mypage
```

This should automatically redirect to:

```
https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/mypage/
```

But it doesn't redirect, and doesn't add the trailing slash.

How can I add to my current htaccess file to catch this condition as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for your testing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to change your last rule to this:

```
# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

While the documentation seems to say that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` could work. Testing it proves it doesn't. And if the request is neither a existing file or directory it probably won't hurt you to add that slash.

Comment: This behaves in the same way as my previous code, and doesn't force a trailing slash if the URL is of the type https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/mypage

Comment: I did test this successfully. Could you try deactivating the other rules to see if it gets stuck somewhere else?